# MYSQL works with Images?

Tags: php, mysql, image

How to store multiple images in a MySQL database and call them back whenever need? I need to store multiple data of people and their pictures for profile functioning on my website. Please help.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

**P. S. -** *I KNOW THERE IS A SOLUTION TO STORE THE FILE ON THE FILESYSTEM. BUT I WANT TO KNOW THE PROCESS OF STORING IT ON DB. SO PLEASE HELP ME INSTEAD OF GIVING ABRUPT ANSWERS.*

Comment: Why don't you store them on filesystem and save on db just the path?

Comment: its okay if i want to store on filesystem, but i want to try out how to store in a db.

Comment: As already said, use a blob field and load files with load_file function(). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also will answer that is not a good idea to do so...

by the way you can do it using BLOB column type and in the upload function you have to insert it into the query as $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']

as example:
`INSERT INTO db_table (id, image) VALUES (NULL, '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}');`

Comment: can you please tell me the way to use the image back on a webpage?

Comment: you can create a page that only show up images with
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

and echo out on the page the field image and put into an <img src="page.php?id=image_id /> (as example)

Comment: I also think you can do something like: <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($image_blob); ?>" border="0" alt="your alternative" />

Comment: That doesn't upload the image to the database, it just saves the filename of the uploaded image.

Comment: My fault... Marc B is right... you have to read the file content before... as ex. $extract = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'r'); 
$content = fread($extract, $size); 
$content = addslashes($content); 
fclose($extract); and then write into the DB the $content

Answer (score 2):

You can use the blob type to store binary data but i would strongly recommend against that.

For performance reasons you should store the images in a data directory and then save the path in the database.

This will allow you to use php's build in file outputting methods (readfile) as well as x-sendfile.

If you need to load the image from the database then you'd be loading the image in php' memory for each request.

But if you really want to do it,

```
<?php
saving the file would be something like this
$file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
$data = addslashes(fread(fopen($file, "r"), filesize($file)));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (file) VALUES ('$data')");
```

just fetch the data from the row and then do something like:

```
 <?php
 $res = mysql_query("select file FROM my_files WHERE file_id=$file_id");
 list($data) = mysql_fetch_row($res);
 header("Content-type: $type");
 header("Content-length: $size");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
 header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
 echo $data;
```

code above is not complete, would need to be cleaned up, have securty checks added, and other stuff that would would want in the table.  just a qucik example

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me quite overkill and not efficient, and I've never heard of anyone storing files directly in a DB.. But then again, I'm note that experienced.

Can't you go with storing your pictures somewhere on your server, and storing the path on the DB ?

Answer (score 0):

use the BLOB datatype.

BLOB stands for Binary Large OBject, and it can be used to store any kind of binary file including images.

Hope this helps.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't store de images in the database.
In a web environment, store the images in your server hard disk (or in a external service like amazon S3 or another solution). In the database you only need to store a reference to this images.

For example, if you have a web in /home/web/ you can create a directory like /home/web/images/. A better practice is create different directories like /home/web/images/2011/03/ because sotore too many files in one directory is not a good idea.

Then, you can store this paths in your user table: 
field image: varchar(XXX) = '/home/web/images/2011/03/image-for-one-user.jpg'

When you write de image in your HTML:

```
<img src="/images/2011/03/image-for-one-user.jpg" />
```

The answer for your question is: You can store binary data in mysql in a blob field.
But I don't like it. think, if you have multiple users, you will have a very large database.